# Как удалить подстроку в строке?

Tags: c#, строки

Например, как можно удалить в строке `\n`?

```
string str= "\n   14.56.67   \n"
```

Comment: *"Все перепробовал"* - что именно?

Answer (score 11):

Суть в том, что все представленные методы - **не меняют** исходную строку.
Таким образом, чтобы получить результат - его нужно присвоить либо этой же переменной, либо другой, например:

```
var replaced = str.Trim();
```

Answer (score 6):

В зависимости от желаемого результата, подойдут `Trim`, `Replace` или `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: стоит добавить, что все эти методы _не меняют_ исходную строку. Вероятно проблема именно из-за этого :)

Comment: @Grundy Кстати, да, немаловероятно, что человеку именно это и нужно было подсказать (что после применения метода в духе `Replace` нужно присвоение результата сделать).

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
str = str.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Источник: [**enSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp).

или:

```
modifiedString = originalString.Replace("\n", "");
```

Источник: [**MS**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fd782e96-dd09-4f74-b580-1b79990dabdc/remove-rn-from-string-start?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: [_public static String NewLine {
            get {
                return **"\r\n"**;
            }
        }_](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,63a04833d43dd9d3) Так что для приведенной строки - не сработает

Comment: str.Replace("\r\n",":");
str.Replace('\r\n',':');
char s = {'\n''});
str.Tim(s);

Comment: Так не получается

Comment: @SVD102 попробуйте сохранять в новую строку. Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать Trim:

```
char[] charsToTrim = {'\n', '\r', ' '};
string str = "\n   14.56.67   \n";
str = str.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Comment: Точно!  Опечаточка

Comment: Ок. Все получилось. Спасибо всем.

Comment: Как-то не так исправил. С каких пор `const char[]` компилируется, если там не `null`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, я знаю, я сразу же закинул вторую правку (пару минут назад), но её все еще не приняли. Вы, кстати, можете её принять.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод строки `Replace`:

```
string text = "123\n321\nabc";
Console.WriteLine(text);

text = text.Replace("\n", "");
Console.WriteLine(text);

Console.Read();
```